# Decode jsonwebtoken into json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

I working with Node and I have a string which is base64 encoded.
The string is an encoded JSON object, how can I decode it and parse it to JSON properly?

I've tried the following but the value in `bufferedString` is not the JSON object string.

```
let splittedString = authenticationToken.split(".");
let bufferedString = Buffer.from(splittedString[2], 'base64').toString('ascii');
let decodedJson = JSON.parse(bufferedString);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does it return before you attempt to parse it as JSON?

Comment: it returns buffer arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWT Structure:

`[signature_or_encryption_algorithm].[payload_as_base64].[verify_signature]`.

The payload usually is the second element so use `splittedString[1]` instead of 2.

But there are better approaches to work with jwt tokens, you can get the payload of a jwt by using `jsonwebtoken` module.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// get the decoded payload ignoring signature, no secretOrPrivateKey needed
var decoded = jwt.decode(token);

// get the decoded payload and header
var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
console.log(decoded.header);
console.log(decoded.payload);
```